# Exporting calculation of all calculated columns

Tags: spotfire

I inherited a couple of reports with several calculated columns. For understanding and documentation I'd need to export all the calculations behind those columns.

Searching the web I couldn't find anything useful.

So far the process is to open properties of each column and manually copy the formula.

Is there something more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a IronPython script to get each Table Name, Column Name and Expression for calculated columns.

```
myDict = {}
#Loop Through All Data Tables 
for x in Document.Data.Tables:
    #Loop Through all Columns in Table
    for z in x.Columns:
        #If Column has an Expression /Is Caculated Column 
        if z.Properties.Expression:
            #Append Items to Dictonary to print at end 
            MyItems = {'Table Name' : x.Name , 'Expression' :z.Properties.Expression  }
            myDict[z.Name] = MyItems
            #Print Each Table Name, Column Name and Expression
            print(x.Name , z.Name , z.Properties.Expression)
#Print Full List 
print myDict
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is via data table properties in the menu bar. Each data table has a "source information" tab that has a step by step recap of the ETL for that table, including joins, transformations, & calculated columns.